Prove that a true, non-empty subset of R has at least 1 boundary point
"Prove that a true, non-empty subset of R has at least 1 boundary point"
I am looking for new ideas in attempting to prove this question. I cannot use the fact that the only open and closed sets are the Reals and the empty set, since this result must be derived from this proof.
I have tried looking at the cases where S is bounded and S unbounded, and while proving it for S bounded is doable, the case where S is unbounded is much more difficult.
I have also tried deriving a contradiction, but once again I cannot use the fact that the set would be clopen as a contradiction.

Isn't the boundary of Q the real numbers? A quick search reveals that and thus the statement still holds...

Consider the line segment between a point in $S$ and a point not in $S$.

What do you mean by "has at least one boundary point", that $\partial S \cap S \neq \emptyset$ or that $\partial S \neq \emptyset$? For the former is $(0,1)$ a counter example.

Suppose that $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is non-empty and $\partial S = \emptyset$. Then $S = \text{int}(S) = \bar S$ and therefore $S$ is clopen. Suppose that there is some $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus S$.
W.l.o.g. let $S \cap (-\infty,a) \neq \emptyset$ (otherwise it is $S \cap (a, \infty) \neq \emptyset$).
Since $S$ is closed there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ with $(a-\varepsilon,a) \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus S$. Then $S \cap (-\infty,a) = S \cap (-\infty,a-\varepsilon]$.
Now, let $s_o := \sup (S \cap (-\infty,a)) = \sup (S \cap (-\infty,a-\varepsilon])$. Since $S$ is closed it is $s_0 \in S \cap (-\infty,a-\varepsilon]$. In particular $s_0 \leq a-\varepsilon < a$. But $S \cap (-\infty,a)$ is also open and therefore $(s_0-\delta,s_0+\delta) \subseteq S\cap(-\infty,a)$ for some $\delta > 0$. Thus $s_0 < s_0 + \delta/2 \in S \cap (-\infty,a)$ a contradiction.
